# The SNMP do not up the 161 port

Tags: snmp, networking

I have a HUAWEI S5720 Switch(manage IP: `10.10.11.118`), and I opened the snmp service of it:

[image]

the configuration is:

```
#                                                                               
snmp-agent                                                                     
snmp-agent local-engineid 800007DB0314A0F8D32960                               
snmp-agent community write cipher %^%#X]&]5GZ*IHd1dP>3b+#B0Tu,WI&Vn(HcHk(qo_a#a`
L@#=3<#R'WZV<6+rH$Wufk)"tc$>3TQt3bH#`2%^%# mib-view private                     
snmp-agent community write cipher %^%#~gYg9hQ-w.9B1K5M:pTDIi%')D)^H;G-z+KtH"GVHB
Wx'L#QEO:aJh2o0K4)7Vis~/Yb(==#YT=AxAsI%^%# mib-view cipher                     
snmp-agent community read cipher %^%#FH_dD(%QTI}$<yFJ@~A/AO^kJi&@Y+^H(;JVxN&Okfz
EMi#boRSZzN9_iD'McX_&NkJk\N8]^s"8<07:%^%# mib-view public                       
snmp-agent sys-info version all                                                 
snmp-agent target-host trap address udp-domain 10.10.11.118 params securityname
cipher %^%#1TD\2&oRjWDQjwJn8:9$WN6<SZ=3)R01'KFE[5gR%^%# v2c                     
snmp-agent mib-view included public iso                                         
snmp-agent trap source Vlanif2                                                 
snmp-agent trap enable                                                         
#
```

Now how can I check if it works fine?

---

My case is, in my manage Server(`10.10.11.249`), which can access the `10.10.11.118`, when I use `nmap` to scan the Switch:

[root@localhost network-scripts]# nmap -p 16-3000 10.10.11.118

```
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2019-06-04 18:29 CST
Nmap scan report for 10.10.11.118
Host is up (0.016s latency).
Not shown: 2982 closed ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
23/tcp  open  telnet
80/tcp  open  http
443/tcp open  https
```

you see, there only shows `23`, `80`, `443` ports, there is no port `161`. who can tell me why the SNMP do not work?

Comment: Run the scan as:
`nmap -sU 10.10.11.118`